# Error creating object in Rails console while using postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm getting an error when trying to create an object in the rails console on my production machine using Postgres, which I'm not getting on my development machine (which currently uses sqlite3).

I have two tables `settings` and `articles`. `settings` is a parent of `articles` so that a "setting" :has_many "articles" and an "article" belongs to one "setting". They look like this it my schema file.

```
create_table "articles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "article_name"
    t.string   "xml_file"
    t.string   "xslt_file"
    t.integer  "setting_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  add_index "articles", ["setting_id"], name: "index_articles_on_setting_id"

create_table "settings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "commentaryid"
    t.string   "logo"
    t.text     "title"
    t.text     "bannermessage"
    t.boolean  "blog"
    t.string   "default_ms_image"
    t.string   "dark_color"
    t.string   "light_color"
    t.string   "commentarydirname"
    t.datetime "created_at",        null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        null: false
    t.boolean  "images"
  end
```

The models for these classes are as follows:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :setting
end

class Setting < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_reader :confighash
  has_many :articles, dependent: :destroy
  after_initialize :set_confighash

 private
  def set_confighash()
    @confighash = { }
    end
end
```

I thought I set these up correctly and everything works fine using sqlite3 on my development machine.

**However, in the rails console on Heroku's server (which uses postgres) I get an error every time I try to create an Article object, like so:**

```
Article.create(article_name: 'biography')
```

**The error is very cryptic. It reads:**

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:375:in `clear_transaction_record_state'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:306:in `ensure in rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:306:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:285:in `save'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:34:in `create'
    from (irb):1
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    from /app/bin/rails:8:in `require'
    from /app/bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Again, I don't have a problem creating the Article object using the same schema while using sqlite3.

I think there is something wrong with the way I have defined the relationship.

Please help.

Comment: have you migrated to the heroku pg database `heroku run rake db:migrate`?

Comment: yes, successfully! No errors on migration

Comment: Does your Article class have any callbacks or custom validations?

Comment: can you please check your model class names whether it is singular ot plural.

Comment: please post your model classes

Comment: @muistooshort the "." is a mistake. I removed it.

Comment: @AmitSharma I've added the models to the original question.

Comment: have you tried this?
`article = Article.new(article_name: 'biography')`
`article.save`

Comment: Article.new(article_name: "biography") returns
=> #<Article not initialized>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78409/discussion-between-jeff-and-amit-sharma).